# Angular typeahead get additional data from array of objects?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects that I use for auto complete, I can successfully make the auto-complete work. Now I also want get masterId  from the object(of selected business name) and add it to a div. Im a newbie in Angularjs

```
<div class="">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
     <a>
     <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
     </a>
  </script>

           <div class="alignhManage">
             <input type="text" ng-change="SetupAutoCom(selectedBusiness)" 
             ng-model="selectedBusiness" placeholder="Search Business" 
             typeahead="c as c.companyName for c in Business | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" typeahead-min-length='2'                
             typeahead-on-select='onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)' 
             typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"">                  
           </div>                                  
</div>



    [{
     "masterId": "1541",
     "companyName": "HENTIQ ",
     "address": { "addressNo": "146" }
    }]
```

Comment: You can have the logic inside function `onSelectPart` by accessing `$item`'s attributes.

Comment: Glad to know that, adding it in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the suggested item, `typeahead-on-select` is invoked. You can have the logic inside function `onSelectPart` by accessing `$item`'s attributes.